# Unexpected identifier in json_encode output

Tags: javascript, php

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){                    
                $("video").easyWebPlayer({ playlist:\''.json_encode($playlist).'\'
                                            });
            });
        </script>';
```

I am using the above code in a php file it produces following output.

```
'playlist:'[{"id":"0","url":"\/26beb276\/26beb276_0.mp4","thumb":"\/26beb276\/26beb276_0.jpg","title":"big buck test"}]'});});
```

It gives me error of Unexpected identifier .
How can I avoid this error.

Comment: You should copy the original error message. `'playlist:'[...]` does not look ok.

Comment: Why do you echo the script tag? Close PHP section `?>`, write HTML/JS code and embed `<?PHP echo json_encode($playlist);?>`. You get less confused since your code becomes more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<Script>
var playlist = '<?php echo $playlist; ?>';
var jsonplaylist = JSON.parse(playlist);
</Script> 
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){ $("video").easyWebPlayer({ playlist:'+jsonplaylist+'});
</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

solved 
I used playlist:"'.str_replace("\"","\'",json_encode($playlist)).'" while json_encode()

and use
var jsonobj=JSON.parse(Playlist.replace(/\'/g, "\""));
at the receiver end.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same console error, the error was due to quotes

Before

```js
<script>window.lang_arr="<?php echo json_encode($lang_arr);?></script>
```

Fix

```js
<script>window.lang_arr=<?php echo json_encode($lang_arr);?></script>
```

It could help someone today :_)